# Get Maximum Value from Dataframe

Tags: pandas, jupyter-notebook

I'm running the following code to get the maximum value in a dataframe.  It works fine.

```
 p_max_shot1_15_CH8 = corrected_shot1_data[['CH 8 [psi]']][0.0119:0.0122].max()
```

I would like to use the max value for math, but it is not a value but another dataframe

```
 CH 8 [psi]    1.419032
 dtype: float64
```

How do I get just the maximum value with no index?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get values without an index using `.values`:

```
p_max_shot1_15_CH8 = corrected_shot1_data[['CH 8 [psi]']][0.0119:0.0122].max().values
```

Alternatively, try putting max first, e.g.:

```
max(p_max_shot1_15_CH8 = corrected_shot1_data[['CH 8 [psi]']][0.0119:0.0122])
```